# AJAX request in Python to get dynamic content in a page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I want to programatically retrieve a list of the top 100 videogames with most runs from the URL https://www.speedrun.com/games#orderby=mostruns

The list in that page is a template in HTML which gets populated via an AJAX request (if I am understanding correctly how this works).

This is the part of the HTML code which I believe its retrieving the games:

```
function getGames(start = 0)
    {
        var hash = getHash();
        if (!hash['orderby']) hash['orderby'] = 'mostactive';
        if (!hash['platform']) hash['platform'] = '';
        if (!hash['title']) hash['title'] = '';
        else $('#title').attr('type', 'text');

        $('#platform').val(hash['platform'].replace('&amp;', '&'));
        $('#orderby').val(hash['orderby']);
        $('#title').val(hash['title'].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

        if (hash['unofficial'] == 'on') $("#checkbox-unofficial").prop("checked", true);
        else if (hash['unofficial'] == 'off') $("#checkbox-unofficial").prop("checked", false);

        $('.col-loadmore').hide();
        $('#spinner').show();

        ajax_users = $.get('/ajax_games.php?game=&platform=' + hash['platform'].replace('&amp;', 'ampersand') + '&unofficial=' + ($("#checkbox-unofficial").prop("checked") ? 'on' : 'off') + '&orderby=' + hash['orderby'] + '&title=' + hash['title'] + '&series=&start=' + start, function(data) {
            $('#list').append(data);
            $('#spinner').hide();

            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            initTimes($('#list'));
            alignImagesTimer();
            resizeListCells();
        });
    }
```

I would like to call that AJAX request from my python interpreter, and get an array with links to the webpages of each of the top 100 videogames (ie `['https://www.speedrun.com/sm64', 'https://www.speedrun.com/mc', ...]`)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an HTTP request in Python, and I recommend the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for achieving this.

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.speedrun.com/ajax_games.php?game=&platform=&unofficial=off&orderby=mostruns&title=&series=&start=0"

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

Here is an example, this code has been ran and tested.

Now, something to note is that this endpoint returns raw HTML, and you'll need a parsing library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to help you clean up the data and get those URLs you're looking for.

I'd do some kind of loop like "get all A tags with attribute data-url=portal, and grab href from tag".